# Passing parameter to isolated scope inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to pass two different parameter to isolated scope inside directive.When I log out values in console then for collapse I am getting true but for infoCard I am getting false value.My question is why I am getting false value for infoCard Thanks in advance.Here is my directive.

```
<display-info user="user" collapse="true" infoCard="true"></display-
info>
```

In my controller i am receiving the parameter,

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('displayInfo', function() {
 return {
  templateUrl: "displayInfo.html",
  restrict: "EA",
  scope: {
   user: '=',
   initialCollapse:'@collapse',
   showInfo:'@infoCard'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.collapse = ($scope.initialCollapse === 'true');
   $scope.infoCard = ($scope.showInfo === 'true');
   console.log("collapse---->",$scope.collapse);
   console.log("displyInfo---->",$scope.infoCard);
  }
 }
});
```

Here is plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/Gng7e4RRVvg8wPOnqQrk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**camel case** convention have problem in directive

**Try this.**

```
<display-info user="user" collapse="true" test="true"></display-info>



 angular.module('myApp').directive('displayInfo', function() {
     return {
      templateUrl: "displayInfo.html",
      restrict: "EA",
      scope: {
       user: '=',
       initialCollapse:'@collapse',
       showInfo:'@test'
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.collapse = ($scope.initialCollapse === 'true');
       $scope.infoCard = ($scope.showInfo === 'true');
       console.log("collapse---->",$scope.collapse);
       console.log("displyInfo---->",$scope.infoCard);
      }
     }
    });
```